# What exactly is Hrudayam?

Tags: scripture, terminology, meaning

There are several similar and related terms in the scriptures of Sanatana Dharma. But there will be subtle differences between those terms. Manas, Chitta, buddhi, Hrudayam are one such example.

Consider the following excerpt taken from Mahabharata

> "Vyasa said, 'The mind creates (within itself) numerous ideas (of
> objects or existent things). The Understanding settles which is which.
> **The heart discriminates which is agreeable and which is disagreeable**.
> These are the three forces that impel to acts....'
>
> [[Section 248, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b075.htm)

The word manas is translated as mind. The word buddhi is translated as understanding. The word Hrudayam is translated as heart. I don't think these translations are correct and exact. There are a few questions related to Manas and Buddhi on our site. But I found no question about the word Hrudayam.

What are/is the exact definition(s) for the word Hrudayam and which definition is apt for the quoted paragraph?

Comment: We will get an idea if we see the Sanskrit verses. Does the same site have the Sanskrit verses too?

Comment: @Rickross I searched for Sanskrit verse and the search is not fruitful. I have Sanskrit verses in my local language. So, I asked accordingly.

Comment: Why does this question get two downvotes?

Comment: Yes, when I saw the question it's score was -2.

Comment: What is the word which has been translated as the heart? is it Hridayam only or some other word used?

Comment: @Rickross It is Hrudayam only.

Comment: Okay ...   @Hanugm